# Introducing a tool for converting a model into database tables

Tags: database

I want to design the EER model and have a tool like a site or program that turns my model into a database table. Can you introduce me to a  free site or program on windows?

Comment: I think it depends very much on which database you use. But, if it is MySql, then you can use [MySql Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), which is free. It also does round trip editting, so that you can generate an EER from an existing datbase, as well as creating the database from the EER like you want to. If you not use MySql, please say which database and we can help you futher

Comment: Thanks
The master of the database course at our university wanted to introduce us to him and he did not think about it for this particular database.If you can give me some more examples @Mawg

Comment: Well, MySql (now forked as MarahDb, and backward compatible) is the [most popular database of 2017](https://www.eversql.com/most-popular-databases-in-2017-according-to-stackoverflow-survey/), so you just have to Google. ***BUT***, what database do you want to use?  Does the person giving the course not tell you? There are similar design tools for some other databases, but you have to say which

Comment: There was no specific database and no restrictions
Each one has a better user interface and is free and learn quickly ... because I need to explain to my other friends how to convert an er model to a DBMS @Mawg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There was no specific database and no restrictions Each one has a
>   better user interface and is free and learn quickly ... because I need
>   to explain to my other friends how to convert an er model to a DBMS

Then, stick with MySql, because it is so widely used, and is more likely to get you a job after Uni.

Use the excellent, powerful, and free [MySql Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/). It also does round trip editting, so that you can generate an EER from an existing database, as well as creating the database from the EER like you want to.

> MySQL Workbench enables a DBA, developer, or data architect to
>   visually design, model, generate, and manage databases. It includes
>   everything a data modeler needs for creating complex ER models,
>   forward and reverse engineering, and also delivers key features for
>   performing difficult change management and documentation tasks that
>   normally require much time and effort. [Learn More»](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/design/)

[image]

Comment: Excuse me but I did not like the program environment
  Suggest me a better site or program
Thanks

Comment: Can you say why you did not like it? Not in a comment here, but by editting your question to describe the features that you want  or do not want.  The more information that you give, the more that we can help you. It might also help you to read [ask]